# visual studio 2013 designer doesn't support CSS3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

> If you use the Web Forms designer in Visual Studio, note that the
>   designer doesn't support CSS3, so it doesn't accurately show all the
>   effects of Bootstrap themes or responsive layout changes. However, the
>   Web Forms pages will display correctly when viewed with a browser.

From: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#bootstrap

The above is a little disappointment, any idea how to make it work in VS 2013, perhaps an update or add-on, or is there any other editor in which designer work properly?

Comment: This is 2016 now and VS2015 Update 3 doesn't yet show Bootstrap layouts correctly. Hello MS???